# React Native fbsdk 0.8.0 version crash the RN project for iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I am building an application from scratch with the latest version of RN: `0.57.0` after setting up all the configuration. I got this error message in the iOS build:

```
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/myUser/Documents/myAwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/third-party/double-conversion-1.1.6/src/cached-powers.cc'

** BUILD FAILED **



The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/myUser/Documents/myAwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/cached-powers.o /Users/myUser/Documents/myAwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/third-party/double-conversion-1.1.6/src/cached-powers.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Any ideas what can I do?